# Bar plot in R using manually input matrix data

Tags: r

I am manually creating a matrix like this:

```
A = matrix(
c("Dp10 WT", "Dp10 WT", "Dp10 WT",
  "Dp10", "Dp10", "Dp10",
  "Dp16 WT", "Dp16 WT", "Dp16 WT",
  "Dp16", "Dp16", "Dp16",
  121.36, 129.11, 149.46, 141.3, 129.11, 131.02,
  0, 134.8, 144.5, 134.33, 129.11, 160.02),
nrow=12,
ncol=2,
byrow = FALSE)
```

Then renaming rows and columns and converting to data frame:

```
dimnames(A) = list(seq(1,12)
,c('Sample', 'Concentration')) # column names
DF=data.frame(A)
```

Then Plotting:

```
melted <- melt(DF, id.vars=c("Sample"))
means <- ddply(melted, c("Sample"), summarise, mean=mean(value))
means.barplot <- qplot(x=group, y=mean, fill=group, data=means, geom="bar", stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

But the ddply line give me the following error:

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What is the problem here? Or even, is there an easier way of plotting a bar plot with std dev as error bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Concentration` data is in `character` format.

You need to change it to `numeric`:

```
DF$Concentration <- as.numeric(DF$Concentration)
```

Also you should check the arguments of `qplot` (e.g. `x=group`, since there is no column named `group` in `means`).